# Decompile Apk but java code giving wrong layout

Tags: java, layout, android-studio, decompiling

I just decompile a apk file and get the java codes but why does the java codes giving wrong id and layouts?

Check image java code giving numbers which is not in the xml.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in the compiling , the compiler automatically replaced the value of ids with the numbers itself. This is the auto-generated values that the compiler gave, so that the app will run faster on the mobile device. In this case, that would be Android. So, the app file will have to be compressed for lower memory and faster functionality. And, when you decompile, you would see the value of the numbers, instead of the initial variables.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't get enough reputation yet to comment. Thanks! Let me just edit it...

Answer (score 0):

Extract the xml files from the APK and then ads them to the project and give them new ids after that but a reference to the new ids in the place where there is numbers